# ng-repeat not working on a bootstrap row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

#### Problem:

I am trying to repeat an array over a bootstrap row but the DOM is not repeating itself with any value.

#### My controller:

```js
$scope.createSummary = function(){

  $scope.entries = [];
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.questions.length;i++){
    $scope.entries.push({
      question : $scope.questions[i].statement,
      correct : $scope.questions[i].correct,
      answered : $scope.answers[i]
    });
  }
  console.log($scope.entries);
  $state.go("home.summary");
}
```

#### My View:

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="mast-head">
   <h2>Match your answers against correct answers.</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div ng-repeat="entry in entries track by $index" class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
   <p> {{$index+1}} <span ng-bind="entry.question"></span><p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
   {{entry.correct}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-offset-1 col-sm-1">
   {{entry.answered}}
  </div>
 </div>  
</div>
```

Please note that this view is one of the many child states, and with this controller as a common controller.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I repeating over the wrong ***`div`***?

Comment: Your view is missing!?

Comment: @AP. i have updated my question

Comment: You are creating scope array...then immediately redirecting to another state. Doesn't make sense. Scope shown will be destroyed when state changes. Need a lot more detail on how states are set up and which one this controller code and view are part of

Comment: @charlietfl this function is implemented in the previous view and in the next view i am trying to repeat the array over the DOM. Both the views share the same controller.And also i have tried to implement ng-repeat using a separate controller but nothing is showing up.

Comment: but each view would initialize a new controller instance. Use a service to share data across controllers/components

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You might should pass arguments to the state you are display and initialize the data in this views controller. I made an example using a service but its not exactly the same as what you will have.  I think it might provide you with enough guidance to get your issue resolved.  The ng-repeat should be fine once you get the data set correctly in the controller.
http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/ZKzMwe/
This is how I defined the service to be able to get and set the questions.  I didn't add a set function for the answers but you should get the idea.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.service('service',
function() {

  this.setQuestions = function(data) {
    questions = data;
  }
  this.getQuestions = function() {
    return questions;
  }
  this.getAnswers = function() {
    return answers;
  }
  var questions = [{
    'statement': 'A Statement 1',
    'correct': false

  }, {
    'statement': 'A Statement 2',
    'correct': false

  }, {
    'statement': 'A Statement 3',
    'correct': false

  }];
  var answers = [
    'Answer 1',
    'Answer 2',
    'Answer 3'
  ];
}
)
```